# Format USB, can no longer mount

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, gparted, unetbootin

I'm trying to use Unetbootin to put Windows7 on my thumbdrive but it says I have to put the USB on a mount point by returning: "/dev/sdc1 not mounted"

When I formatted my USB (to fat32), it no longer automatically mounts, and when I try to manually mount it in gparted, the option is greyed.

In gparted, there are two strange pending operations.
How do I get my USB to mount so I can use it properly?

[image]

Thanks.

I have previously tried
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1 bs=512 count=1` and re-formatting and that's when those odd pending operations came up.

After going under "Edit" in Gparted and clicking "Apply All Operations" as I've done before, I reach this part, but I still can't mount it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant comment as I do not have enough reputation, but what error message does it exactly give when you try to mount it?

Did you try the following?
Go to dash and type disks-> Then in the application, click on the disk in the left side, then select the partition you want to mount on the right and click the play icon below it.

If the above does not work, as it is you are trying to make it bootable, so I assume there is no data on it.
So, Go to GParted-> click Device->New Partition Table-> Select msdos-> Then repartition the drive and then see if you can mount the drive by the above method.

Also, I have noticed, that when Gparted is open, you cannot access the drives through the file managers or the terminal through "mount /dev/sdxy". This seems to be new in Ubuntu 16.04. 
So, close Gparted, wait for some time and reinsert the pendrive if it does not mount.

Comment: No error messages, I just can't mount it (grey in gparted). When I type `sudo mount /dev/sdc1` into the terminal, it says `can't find /dev/sdc1 in etc/fstab`

Comment: By the way, which is your Ubuntu falvour?

Comment: Just try closing GParted and then trying, or after rebooting your PC.

Comment: Kubuntu, so I don't have Disks installed by default.

Comment: I have noticed it in Ubuntu 16.04 that sometimes, you cannot access the disks when GParted is open. Unless they were mounted before, they do not even appear in Nautilus.

Comment: So, did you try it after closing Gparted?

Comment: interesting, and yes, I did reboot but theres still no mount option in gparted nor automatic mounting happening (and I did try the last thing you suggested in your official answer before rebooting, no changes)

Comment: I just checked in my Computer. The mount option is greyed out too, also I cannot use mount /dev/sdxy through. But, once I close Gparted, after some time I can access the disk. So, do one thing, close Gparted, wait for a few minutes, and see if you can mount it. Or after some time, remove the Pendrive and insert it again, and then check if you can mount it.

Comment: ohwow! I closed gparted, removed the usb, opened Steam, then put the USB in again (all within half a minute to a minute) and it recognized + automatically mounted the usb! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great!!! Happy to Help :)

Comment: I`ll just edit the answer.